# xcodebuild equivalent of Xcode's "Product > Build For > Testing"

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

I'm trying to write a script that submits iOS apps to AppThwack (a 'real device' UI testing service). Their guidance is to use the Xcode GUI and build the app using the `Build For > Testing` option in the Xcode `Product` menu. This works, but I haven't been able to translate this into the `xcodebuild` equivalent.

More generally, how do we determine what arguments Xcode is passing to xcodebuild (assuming it uses that tool).

Comment: Xcode isn't passing arguments to `xcodebuild`.  Anyway look at the `-scheme` and `-configuration` command line options (i.e. see the man page).

Comment: Isn't it the case that you need to use this docs https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/A2-command_line_testing/A2-command_line_testing.html, but instead of invoking `test` action, `build` should be run? Please try and then submit created archive.

Answer (score 7):

This is now possible as of Xcode 8 (in beta at time of writing). Use `build-for-testing`.

Example:

`xcodebuild -workspace <workspace> -scheme <scheme> -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' build-for-testing`

To switch to a beta version of xcodebuild, use `xcode-select`:

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer`

Answer (score 1):

[xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool#building-tests) has a flag called `build-tests` that will do just that.

(As of this post, it is not currently Xcode 7 compatible, but they are working on it.)